# What is the logic behind results.next()?

Tags: java, jdbc

```
ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery(sb.toString())) {
List<Artists> artists = new ArrayList<>();
while(results.next()){
    Artists artist = new Artists();
    artist.setId(results.getInt(INDEX_ARTIST_ID));
    artist.setName(results.getString(INDEX_ARTIST_NAME));
    artists.add(artist);
}
return artists;
```

I am trying to get all the records that is stored in results. If I reached the last element results.next() will be false. So how can be the last element added here? Can someone please explain clearly what is going on this loop?

Comment: *" I reached the last element results.next() will be false."* -- no, not so. It will be false when you have run out of records. The last record should add just fine.

Comment: Did you read [javadocs for ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next())?

Answer (score 2):

If the query returns e.g. 3 rows, your code will call [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--) 4 times.

On the first 3 calls it returns `true`, and the column values of the row is available through the `getXxx()` methods.

On the 4th call, `next()` returns `false` and no row is available, i.e. the `getXxx()` methods will throw exception if you try to call them.

This is all explained in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--):

> Moves the cursor forward one row from its current position. A `ResultSet` cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.
>
> When a call to the `next` method returns `false`, the cursor is positioned after the last row. Any invocation of a `ResultSet` method which requires a current row will result in a `SQLException` being thrown.